# normal distribution curve doesn't fit well over histogram in subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, subplot, normal-distribution

I am using "plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)" to draw a 2*2 subplots. Each subplot has two Y axis and contains normal distribution curve over a histogram. Noting I particularly set "sharex=True, sharey=True" here in order to make all subplots share the same X axis and Y axis.

After running my code, everything is fine except the second, three, and fourth subplots where the normal distribution curve doesn't fit the histogram very well (please see the figure here)

[image]

I did googling but failed to get this issue solved. However, if I set "sharex=True, sharey=False" in my code, then the figure looks correct, but all subplots use their own Y axix which isn't what I want. Please see the figure here

[image]

Hope this issue can be fixed by experts in StackOverflow. Many thanks in advance!

Below is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.stats import norm

def align_yaxis(ax1, v1, ax2, v2):
    #adjust ax2 ylimit so that v2 in ax2 is aligned to v1 in ax1
    _, y1 = ax1.transData.transform((0, v1))
    _, y2 = ax2.transData.transform((0, v2))
    inv = ax2.transData.inverted()
    _, dy = inv.transform((0, 0)) - inv.transform((0, y1-y2))
    miny, maxy = ax2.get_ylim()
    ax2.set_ylim(miny+dy, maxy+dy)
    
def drawSingle(myax, mydf , title, offset):
    
    num_bins = 200
    xs = mydf["gap"]
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
    
    mu =np.mean(x) 
    sigma =np.std(xs)
    n, bins, patche =  myax.hist(xs, num_bins, alpha=0.8, facecolor='blue', density=False) 
    

    myax.set_ylabel('frequency',color="black",fontsize=12, weight = "bold")
    myax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=12, weight = "bold",horizontalalignment='center')

    ax_twin = myax.twinx()
    y_normcurve = norm.pdf(bins, mu, sigma)
    ax_twin.plot(bins, y_normcurve, 'r--') 

    align_yaxis(myax,0,ax_twin,0)
    peakpoint = norm.pdf(mu,loc=mu,scale=sigma)
    plt.vlines(mu, 0, peakpoint, 'y', '--', label='example')
    
    ax_twin.set_ylabel("probablility dense",color="black",fontsize=12, weight = "bold")
    
         
def drawSubplots(mydf1,mydf2,mydf3,mydf4, pos1,pos2,pos3,pos4, title, filename):
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18,15 )
    
    my_x_ticks = np.arange(-0.8, 0.8,0.1)
   
    rows, cols = 2, 2
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

    drawSingle(ax[0][0], mydf1, "Subplot1", pos1)
    drawSingle(ax[0][1], mydf2, "Subplot2", pos2)
    drawSingle(ax[1][0], mydf3, "Subplot3", pos3)
    drawSingle(ax[1][1], mydf4, "Subplot4", pos4)
    
    plt.text(-1, -1, title, horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=18)
    
    plt.show()

    
drawSubplots(df1, df2,df3,df4,3.2,3.1,2.7,2.85,"test9", "test9")
```

Comment: Note that with `sharey=True`, the histograms of dataframes with less rows will be smaller. If you want those to have a similar height, you need to normalize the heights with `hist(..., density=True)` (this scales their area to 1).

Comment: You need `density=True` to properly fit the normal curve. Or, otherwise, multiply `y_normcurve` with `len(xs)` and by the binwidth (`y_normcurve*len(xs)*(bins[1]-bins[0)`) to have their area equal.  Better leave out the `twinx()` and plot everything on the same `ax`. Also, `mu=np.mean(xs)` is more appropriate than `mu=np.mean(x)`.  Finally, the curve would look better with `y_normcurve = norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma)` and also draw it as `myax.plot(x, ....)`

Comment: Hi JohanC, thanks a lot for your help!. I followed your advice and revised the code in the function of drawSingle. (set density=True)
Now, the normal distribution curve looks fitting better over the histogram, however the left Y axis in each plot is not frequency. Can I still have two Y axis (the left one for frequency, the right one for probablity dense)?
Thanks again!

Comment: also, I am not quite understanding what you mean (y_normcurve*len(xs)*(bins[1]-bins[0)) to have their area equal). Could you kindly please advise me how to do it in the code? Thanks again!

Comment: With `density=True`, the y-axis will be the height of the "probabiliy distribution function". Note that "frequency" is only a useful measure if you have a well-defined bin width. If you use `bins=200`, the bin width will be `(xs.max() - xs.min()) / 200` which is different in the 4 plots.  Multiplying `(y_normcurve*len(xs)*(bins[1]-bins[0))` is only needed if you'd use `density=False`.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Yep, I understood (y_normcurvelen(xs)*(bins[1]-bins[0)) is only needed when I set density = False. but don't know where I should use (y_normcurvelen(xs)*(bins[1]-bins[0)) in the code? Could you please point this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt to:

- have the left y-axes being "frequency" (which is very uninformative in the case of the current bin widths) and shared among the 4 subplots
- have the right y-axes be a "probability density"; note how the top of all gaussians is around y=0.02 (the twin axes can only be set at the end because the shared y axes can be updated via later subplots)
- have the histogram and the normal curve aligned

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm

def drawSingle(myax, mydf, title):
    num_bins = 200
    xs = mydf["gap"]
    x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)

    mu = np.mean(x)
    sigma = np.std(xs)
    n, bins, patches = myax.hist(xs, num_bins, alpha=0.8, facecolor='blue', density=False)

    myax.set_ylabel('frequency', color="black", fontsize=12, weight="bold")
    myax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize=12, weight="bold", horizontalalignment='center')

    normalization_factor = len(xs) * (bins[1] - bins[0])
    y_normcurve = norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma) * normalization_factor
    myax.plot(x, y_normcurve, 'r--')
    myax.vlines(mu, 0, y_normcurve.max(), 'y', '--', color='lime', label='example')
    return normalization_factor

def drawSubplots(mydf1, mydf2, mydf3, mydf4, title):
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18, 15)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

    dfs = [mydf1, mydf2, mydf3, mydf4]
    norm_factors = [drawSingle(ax_i, df, title)
                    for ax_i, df, title in zip(ax.ravel(), dfs, ["Subplot1", "Subplot2", "Subplot3", "Subplot4"])]
    for ax_i, norm_factor in zip(ax.ravel(), norm_factors):
        ax_twin = ax_i.twinx()
        ymax = ax_i.get_ylim()[1]
        ax_twin.set_ylim(0, ymax / norm_factor)
    plt.suptitle(title, fontsize=18)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

df1, df2, df3, df4 = [pd.DataFrame({"gap": np.random.normal(0, 0.2, n)}) for n in [6000, 4000, 1800, 1200]]
drawSubplots(df1, df2, df3, df4, "Title")
```

[image: subplots with aligned histograms]

Comment: Hi JohanC, still one more confusion about the right Y-axis ticks. I run your code and noted that the right Y-axis ticks don't reflect the correct value of probability dense. Could you kindly please advise how to adjust the code, so that it exactly shows the value of probability dense. Specifically, the top of all Gaussians is around y=0.02, however, use "norm.pdf(mu,loc=mu,scale=sigma)" to calculate the probability dense for the top of each  Gaussians, they are all around 1.9855. Is it wrong to use "norm.pdf(mu,loc=mu,scale=sigma)" to calculate the probability dense? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good catch, you are right. I should have checked things more carefully. `0.02` is the max when sigma is 1, but here sigma is much smaller, pushing the maximum higher.  The bug was reading `xlim` instead of `ylim`. I'll correct the code and image. Thanks again for checking things out and letting me know.

Comment: Thank you JohanC very much for your help! It is correct now. Beautiful graph, very nice work:)

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks JohanC, you are amazing.

Based on your code, I just added a few lines of code within drawSubplots function in order to make 95% of the Gaussian curve area shaded between the lower bound and upper bound for each subplot. The following is my try. It seems that ax_twin.fill_between doesn't work normally here. As you could see from the figure that the shaded area is out of the Gaussian curve [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpObh.png). What I want is only to shade the area under the Gaussian curve between the lower bound and upper bound. If you don't mind, would you please check it out my mistake? Thank you very much!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

from scipy.stats import norm

def align_yaxis(ax1, v1, ax2, v2):
    #adjust ax2 ylimit so that v2 in ax2 is aligned to v1 in ax1
    _, y1 = ax1.transData.transform((0, v1))
    _, y2 = ax2.transData.transform((0, v2))
    inv = ax2.transData.inverted()
    _, dy = inv.transform((0, 0)) - inv.transform((0, y1-y2))
    miny, maxy = ax2.get_ylim()
    ax2.set_ylim(miny+dy, maxy+dy)
    
    

def drawSingle(myax, mydf , title):
    
    num_bins = 200
    xs = mydf["gap"]
    x = np.linspace(-1,1,1000)
 
    mu =np.mean(xs) 
    sigma =np.std(xs)
    
    n, bins, patches = myax.hist(xs, num_bins, alpha=0.8, facecolor='blue', density=False)
    

    myax.set_ylabel('Frequency', color="black", fontsize=12, weight="bold")
    myax.set_xlabel(title, fontsize=12, weight="bold", horizontalalignment='center')

    normalization_factor = len(xs) * (bins[1] - bins[0])
    y_normcurve = norm.pdf(x, mu, sigma) * normalization_factor
    myax.plot(x, y_normcurve, 'r--')

    myax.vlines(mu, 0, y_normcurve.max(), 'y', '--', color='lime', label='example')
    
    plt.xlim(-0.8,0.8) 
    my_x_ticks = np.arange(-0.8, 0.8,0.1)
    plt.xticks(my_x_ticks)

    return normalization_factor, mu, sigma
    
    
def drawSubplots(mydf1,mydf2,mydf3,mydf4, title):
    plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (18,15 )
    
    norm_factors = []
    mus = []
    sigmas = []
    
    my_x_ticks = np.arange(-0.8, 0.8,0.1)
    
    
    rows, cols = 2, 2
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, sharex=True, sharey=True)
    

    dfs = [mydf1, mydf2, mydf3, mydf4]
    #norm_factors = [drawSingle(ax_i, df, title)
                    #for ax_i, df, title in zip(ax.ravel(), dfs, ["Subplot1", "Subplot2", "Subplot3", "Subplot4"])]
    
    
    for ax_i, df, title in zip(ax.ravel(), dfs, ["Subplot1", "Subplot2", "Subplot3", "Subplot4"]):
        norm_factor, mu, sigma = drawSingle(ax_i, df, title)
        norm_factors.append(norm_factor)
        mus.append(mu)
        sigmas.append(sigma)
    
    
    for ax_i, norm_factor, mu, sigma in zip(ax.ravel(), norm_factors, mus, sigmas ):
        ax_twin = ax_i.twinx()
        
        xmax = ax_i.get_xlim()[1]
        ax_twin.set_ylim(0, xmax / norm_factor)
        ax_twin.set_ylabel("probablility dense",color="black",fontsize=12, weight = "bold")
        
        
        CI_95_lower = mu - (1.96*sigma)
        CI_95_upper = mu + (1.96*sigma)

        px_shaded = np.arange(CI_95_lower,CI_95_upper,0.1)
        ax_twin.fill_between(px_shaded,norm.pdf(px_shaded,loc=mu,scale=sigma) * norm_factor,alpha=0.75, color='pink')
        area_shaded_95_CI = norm.cdf(x=CI_95_upper, loc=mu, scale=sigma)-norm.cdf(x=CI_95_lower, loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        ax_twin.text(-0.06,0.01,str(round(area_shaded_95_CI*100,1))+"%", fontsize=20)
       
        ax_twin.annotate(s=f'lower bound= {CI_95_lower:.3f}',xy=(CI_95_lower,norm.pdf(CI_95_lower,loc=mu,scale=sigma)),xytext=(-0.75,0.01),weight='bold',color='blue',\
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>',connectionstyle='arc3',color='green'),\
                 fontsize=12
                )

        ax_twin.annotate(s=f'upper bound= {CI_95_upper:.3f}',xy=(CI_95_upper,norm.pdf(CI_95_upper,loc=mu,scale=sigma)),xytext=(0.28,0.01),weight='bold',color='blue',\
                 arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='-|>',connectionstyle='arc3',color='green'),\
                  fontsize=12
                )

        ax_twin.text(0.05, 0.03, r"$\mu=" + f'{mu:.6f}' + ", \sigma=" + f'{sigma:.6f}' + "$" + ", confidence interval=95%" ,
            horizontalalignment='center', fontsize=15)
        
        
    
    plt.suptitle(title, fontsize=18)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()


df1, df2, df3, df4 = [pd.DataFrame({"gap": np.random.normal(0, 0.2, n)}) for n in [6000, 4000, 1800, 1200]]

drawSubplots(df1, df2, df3, df4, "Title")
```

Comment: Hi JohanC, I figured it out. The correct way is to move all my added codes into the function of drawSingle where I use myax to draw shaded areas and add annotations.
Huge thanks for your help!  Really appreciated!